# Force Unique Insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with a "unique" column, I occasionally need to insert some data into it so I am wondering is there any keyword that I can pass in order for mysql to generate a unique string that does not yet exist in the table? I would really not change the schema since it's already populated.

Comment: Why is the column unique?  Why do you want to shove any old data into it?

Comment: If you already have an auto-increment ID field, you can base it on that? Any currently unique code that you append that ID to will be unique as well. If you don't have an auto-increment, you might want to consider making one. It is entirely possible to change the schema without messing up the data, so that's not a real issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try uuid().  This should return a unique universal identifier.

```
insert into table(uniquecolumn)
    select uuid()
```

Comment: Then how do you know what the UUID is though?

Comment: You would be inserting it into a column and you can see the value there.